# Using pdfminer python to extract information from PDF file

Tags: python, spyder, pdfminer

I met a problem when I tried to use `pdfminer` to extract certain information from a PDF file in Spyder. I followed `pdfminer` official documentation trying to define an extraction function first;

```
# Define a pdf-to-txt function
def pdftotxt(path, new_name):
    # Create a pdf parser
    parser = PDFParser(path)
    # Create an object storing information
    document = PDFDocument(parser)
    # Evaluate if extractable
    if not document.is_extractable:
        raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed
    else:
        # Create a PDF resource management to restore resource
        resmag = PDFResourceManager()
        # Set a parameter for analysis
        laparams = LAParams()
        # Create a PDF object
        # device = PDFDevice(resmag)
        device = PDFPageAggregator(resmag,laparams=laparams)
        # Create a PDF interpreter
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resmag, device)
        # Analyzing each page
        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(document):
            interpreter.process_page(page)
            # Assign LTPage of this page
            layout = device.get_result()
            for y in layout:
                if(isinstance(y,LTTextBoxHorizontal)):
                    with open("%s"%(new_name),'a',encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        f.write(y.get_text()+"\n")  

# Get a PDF's directory to test
path = open('/keep_2.pdf')
pdftotxt(path, "pdfminer.txt")
```

But it returns an error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-2-11f054ad4321>", line 31, in <module>
    pdftotxt(path, "pdfminer.txt")

  File "<ipython-input-2-11f054ad4321>", line 5, in pdftotxt
    document = PDFDocument(parser)

  File "/Users/WQY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py", line 557, in __init__
    pos = self.find_xref(parser)

  File "/Users/WQY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py", line 759, in find_xref
    for line in parser.revreadlines():

  File "/Users/WQY/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 268, in revreadlines
    n = max(s.rfind(b'\r'), s.rfind(b'\n'))

TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Can anyone help solve this error? I tried to google it but it seems no similar problems in using `pdfminer` being reported. Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Instead of `open('/keep_2.pdf')` use `open('/keep_2.pdf', 'rb')` to open in binary mode.

Comment: Hi @jdaz, thank you so much for the help. It worked! Would you mind my asking a follow-up question? Do you know how I can segment the pdf according to some pre-defined tags within the pdf file? Now I can get a txt file with a kind of messy structure and no idea how I can proceed the segment.

Comment: Good to hear! You could output the file as `pdfminer.xml` instead and then parse the XML file, looking for the tags you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer so this doesn't look like an unanswered question to people scrolling through:

Instead of `open('/keep_2.pdf')`, use `open('/keep_2.pdf', 'rb')` to open in binary mode.